# build error while building android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I am building android source code on ubuntu 10.04.While Building source code I got following build error.

> javadoc: error - In doclet class com.google.doclava.Doclava,  method
>   start has thrown an exception
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty()Z

I am using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

Comment: The patch given on this http://code.google.com/p/doclava/issues/detail?id=29 work for me but I am not sure this is correct......??